# Is there an infinite depth irreducible finite index maximal subfactor (other than Temperley Lieb) ?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, von-neumann-algebras, subfactors

A subfactor $N \subset M$ is maximal if it admits no non-trivial intermediate subfactors $N \subset P \subset M$.

Is there an infinite depth irreducible finite index maximal subfactor (other than Temperley-Lieb $A_{\infty} $) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The infinite depth subfactor coming from SU(3) at any index above 9 gives an example.  Here the Q-system is $V_{(1,0)} \otimes V_{(0,1)} \cong V_{(1,1)} \oplus V_{(0,0)}$ so the only possible sub-objects are the whole thing or the trivial, so it's certainly maximal.

Comment: I see, thank you. Maybe there are such examples for every simple Lie groups... 

Comment: In general it'd probably be a bit tricky to work out whether the subfactor is maximal.  But for SU(n) the same argument should work.

Comment: In my opinion, it would be a nice work to exhibit every infinite depth irreducible finite index maximal subfactors coming from the simple Lie groups.