# About the classification of infinite depth irreducible finite index maximal subfactors

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, subfactors, qa.quantum-algebra, von-neumann-algebras, fusion-categories

The Temperley Lieb subfactors $A_{\infty}$ are the first examples of infinite depth irreducible finite index maximal subfactors. We can see these subfactors as coming from the simple Lie group $SU(2)$.

I first asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132881/is-there-an-infinite-depth-irreducible-finite-index-maximal-subfactor-other-than) if there exists others infinite depth irreducible finite index maximal subfactors.

Noah Snyder answered "yes" by giving others examples coming from $SU(3)$.

**Question:** What's the classification of all the infinite depth irreducible finite index maximal subfactors coming from the simple Lie groups ?

Bonus open problem: is there exist such a subfactor **not** coming from a group.